# Change prompt to user with each loop pass

Tags: python, loops

How can I create a loop that prompts for a list of items, with the prompt changing each time.

For example "Input your first item" then "Input your second item" etc... (or 1st, 2nd)

I need to add all of the items to an array:

```
items = []
for i in range(5):
    item = input("Input your first thing: ")
    items.append(item)
print (items)
```

Comment: If you want to use "First" "Second" etc, you'll want to whip up an array of all those words to correspond to the iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly altering your code:

```
names = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third"    # and so on...
        }

items = []

for i in range(5):
    item = input("Input your {} thing: ".format(names[i+1])
    items.append(item)
print(items)
```

Or a more general version:

def getordinal(n):
    if str(n)[-2:] in ("11","12","13"):
        return "{}th".format(n)
    elif str(n)[-1] == "1":
        return "{}st".format(n)
    elif str(n)[-1] == "2":
        return "{}nd".format(n)
    elif str(n)[-1] == "3":
        return "{}rd".format(n)
    else:
        return "{}th".format(n)

Or a more compact definition:

```
def getord(n):
    s=str(n)
    return s+("th" if s[-2:] in ("11","12","13") else ((["st","nd","rd"]+
                                                        ["th" for i in range(7)])
                                                        [int(s[-1])-1]))
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a list of prompts:

```
prompts = ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth')

items = []
for prompt in prompts:
    item = input("Input your {} thing: ".format(prompt))
    items.append(item)
```

Comment: or `items = [input("Input your {} thing: ".format(prompt)) for prompt in prompts]`

Comment: or items =[input("Input your {} thing: ".format(prompt)) for prompt in ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth')]

;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use string formatting? Something along the lines of

```
>>> for i in range(5):
        items.append(input("Enter item at position {}: ".format(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items = OrderedDict.fromkeys(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'])

for item in items:
    items[item] = raw_input("Input your {} item: ".format(item))


print items
```

Output:

```
Input your first item: foo
Input your second item: bar
Input your third item: baz
Input your fourth item: python
Input your fifth item: rocks

OrderedDict([('first', 'foo'), ('second', 'bar'), ('third', 'baz'), ('fourth', 'python'), ('fifth', 'rocks')])
```